# Is there a quicker way to apply brightness in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

In my application I have the following code which changes the brightness of a pixel by 20.

```
    for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    { 
        for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
        { 
            for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
            {
                src.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>( ( src.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ) + 20 );
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of applying this effect?

Comment: At some level this will have to be done anyway. It seems like the most efficient you will be able to achieve. It's also the way opencv teaches you to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you cannot/do not simply use:

```
src = src + cv::Scalar(20,20,20);
```

Would this not do the job?