# Changing brightness and contrast of an image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on the following code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat change(Mat m);

int main()

{
    Mat image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg");

    Mat copy = Mat::zeros(image.size(),image.type());

    Mat changedImage = change(copy);

    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",changedImage);

    waitKey(0);
}

Mat change(Mat m)
{
    int cols = m.cols;
    int rows = m.rows;

    double alpha = 2.2;
    int beta = 50;


    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
        {
            m.at<Vec3b>(rows,c)[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0]) + beta);
            m.at<Vec3b>(rows,c)[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(rows,cols)[1]) + beta);
            m.at<Vec3b>(rows,c)[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(rows,cols)[2]) + beta);
        }
    }

    return m;

}
```

This compiles fine, but when I run this, I get the following error

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file c:\opencv\build\inclu
de\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 534
```

Why I am getting this? I guess I have done everything correctly.

Comment: Hi, why not use matrix arithmetic operators like in this question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473695/is-there-a-quicker-way-to-apply-brightness-in-opencv/16477401#16477401]

Comment: changedimage=(2.2*image)+cvScalar(50,50,50);

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat change(Mat m);

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg");

    Mat changedImage = change(image); //Modified

    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",changedImage);

    waitKey(0);
}

Mat change(Mat m)
{
    int cols = m.cols;
    int rows = m.rows;

    double alpha = 2.2;
    int beta = 50;

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
        {
            m.at<Vec3b>(i,c)[0] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(i,c))[0]) + beta);  //Modified
            m.at<Vec3b>(i,c)[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(i,c))[1]) + beta);  //Modified
            m.at<Vec3b>(i,c)[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha* (m.at<Vec3b>(i,c))[2]) + beta);  //Modified
        }
    }

    return m;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Mat Change(Mat input,int beta = 50)
{
Mat Output;

Scalar S(beta,beta,beta);
cv::add(input,S,Output);

return Output;
}
```